# How to Substitute bind_result for get_result in my code

Tags: php, mysqli

I have seen tips on how to use bind_result(); other places but I can't quite figure out how to change my code to continue working. get_result(); doesn't work because Mysqlnd is not available on the webhost company i am using. This is the only issue I am having before successfully launching my website. Can anyone give me pointers on how to modify this function to be acceptable for a web server without the necessary drivers to use mysqlnd?

```
function selectAll($table, $conditions = []){

    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    //dd($sql);
    if (empty($conditions)){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }
    else {
        //return records that match conditions ...

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0) {
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?";
            }
            $i++;

        }

        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }

}
```

I have successfully recreated an array but the array does not contain any values

```
class Top {
    var $id;
    var $topic; 
    var $description;

    //Methods
    function set_id($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    function get_id($id){
        return $this->id= $id;
    }
    function set_topic($topic){
        $this->topic = $topic;
    }
    function get_topic($topic){
        return $this-> $topic;
    }
    function set_description($description){
        $this->description = $description;
    }
    function get_description($description){
        $this-> $description;
    }
}

    $sql = 'SELECT id, topic, description FROM topics';
    //dd($sql);
    //$id = 5;
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){

        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $id, $topic, $description);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

        $stmt->bind_result($id, $topic, $description);

        $topic_array = array();
        while ($top = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $t = new Top($id, $topic, $description);
            array_push($topic_array, $t);

        }
        dd($topic_array);

        $stmt->free_result();

        $stmt->close();
    }

    $conn->close();
```

Comment: I don't recommend doing this. Just find a better hosting.

Comment: Rewrite your database interactions to PDO

Comment: However, in this particular case your problem has nothing to do store_result, mysqli or a database. That's your Top class that does absolutely nothing if you create it as `new Top($id, $topic, $description);` and naturally you get empty properties.